# Neural Networks works worse than RandomForest

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have a classification problem that target contains 5 classes, 15 features(all continuous)
and have 1 million for training data, 0.5 million for validation data.
e.g.,

```
shape of X_train = (1000000,15)
shape of X_validation = (500000,15)
```

First, I used Random Forest that can get 88% Avg. Accuracy.

After that I tried many Neural Network architecture, the best one got ~80% Avg. Accuracy both on training and validation data, which was worse than Random forest.
(I don't know much about designing Neural Network architecture)

Following is the best one of my NN architecture. (~80% Avg.Accuracy)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(900, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(800, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(700, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(600, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))#output layer
adadelta = Adadelta()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adadelta, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Batch Size = 128 and epochs = 100

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459022/neural-network-in-tensorflow-works-worse-than-random-forest-and-predict-the-same). The answer point out that NN needs amount of data and some regulization. I think my data size is good enough and I have also tried higer Dropout rate and L2 regulization but still not working. 
What could the problem be?

This is biological data that I have no domain knowledge so sorry about that I can't explain it. I've plot the feature distribution as below, all features are between 0 to 3
[image]

Comment: Tell us something about your data. What is it? What are the features? We need to more more about your data, and the likely structures that will be reflected in its makeup. That allows you to select a NN architecture that is appropriate and will likely be able to find a solution to your problem. The appropriate NN architectures basically restricts the neural connections to something that will be much closer to your end solution. You have chosen an extremely general network architecture (4 dense layers). I would say it is unlikely to be particularly good at anything in particular

Comment: Why should a NN be better in the first place? Different hypothesis may give a better of worse fit on your data.

Comment: I have updated some information, hope that would be helpful for understanding.  I agree with @cheersmate , I want to know is there any problem with my NN architecture, I think it could be better.

Comment: Pick the best model for the task. Why would you assume its a NN? (NN hype..) Try XGboost!